# How can I write if statement in a line?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to set `@community_topic.comment_threads.last.created_at` into `last_comment_time` when `@community_topic.comment_threads.last.created_at` is not `nil`
When it's nil, I want to set `commentable.created_at` instead.

How can I write? I tried this but I've got error back:(

```
last_comment_time = @community_topic.comment_threads.last.created_at || commentable.created_at
```

Comment: What's your error? If you are using ActiveRecords, I'm not sure I understand when `created_at` would be `nil`, unless you've added a new thread and not saved yet; or you have not `comment_threads` but then `last` would return the `nil`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
last_comment_time = @community_topic.comment_threads.last.created_at.nil? ? commentable.created_at : @community_topic.comment_threads.last.created_at
```

Interestingly, there is a `conditional operator` tag on Stack Overflow that explains how the conditional operator works:

"The conditional operator, represented by the characters ? and :, is a ternary operator that is part of the syntax for a basic conditional expression in several programming languages. It is also commonly referred to as the ternary operator or inline if. It is used as follows: (condition) ? (value...)"

The : would then stand in for `else`.

Comment: No problem, just re-read the first few chapters of "Eloquent Ruby" last night so it was fresh in my mind!

Comment: This is no different than the OP's line of code that was stated returned an error. In Ruby a `nil` is evaluated as `false` and would fall through the `||` check to run `commentable.created_at`. IMHO the OP's original code is clearer.

Comment: OP's code will work assuming there is a comment thread in `@community_topic`. See my answer for further detail.

Answer (score 3):

Personally I think this is more readable than the ternary operator.

```
last_comment_time = 
  if @community_topic.comment_threads.last.created_at.nil?
    commentable.created_at
  else
    community_topic.comment_threads.last.created_at
  end
```

More lines are not necessarily a bad thing if you are sacrificing clarity.

As far as your code:

```
last_comment_time = @community_topic.comment_threads.last.created_at || commentable.created_at
```

This is the best way to do it. You are most likely getting an error because `.last` is returning `nil` (this is what happens when there are no records in the scope it's being called on). So in this case it is likely that you don't have any threads under the `@community_topic`.

Ruby offers a method called `try`, which will call a method and return `nil` if the method is being called on Nil::NilClass (as opposed to throwing a NoMethodError exception).

This can be used in your line of code like this:

```
last_comment_time = @community_topic.comment_threads.last.try(:created_at) || commentable.created_at
```

So `last` will return nil, then try to call `created_at`. Because `created_at` is being called on nil using `try`, it will also return nil and so the variable will be set to `commentable.created_at`.

Comment: I also should mention that the if statement in the top example will also throw an exception, since it is still calling `created_at` on `last`, which can potentially be nil.

Comment: I like ternary operators but tomato tomato, right? Your modification on the OG question is spot-on.

Comment: IMO ternary should be used for very short and simple lines. `<%= self.active ? 'Active' : 'Inactive' %>`, for example.